# A* only works in certain cases

Tags: ios, objective-c, path-finding, shortest-path, a-star

My a* path finding algorithm only works for certain cases but I don't understand why. Every node in my grid is walkable so in theory every path should work. I believe the error is in this line:

```
 PathFindingNode *neighbor = NULL;
            if ((y > 0 && x > 0) && (y < gridY - 1 && x < gridX - 1))
             neighbor = [[grid objectAtIndex:x + dx] objectAtIndex:y +dy];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In function `-(void)addNeighbors:`, the line

```
if ((y > 0 && x > 0) && (y < gridY - 1 && x < gridX - 1))
    neighbor = [[grid objectAtIndex:x + dx] objectAtIndex:y +dy];
```

has bug because if `curNode` is on boundary, it does not add neighbors to the queue. So that  the algorithm will never reach `endNode` in the four corners (i.e. [0,0], [gridX-1,0], [0,gridY-1], [gridX-1,gridY-1]).

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, I would upvote you if I could but I don't have enough reputation. This is one of those bugs you miss after staring at something for 6 hours into the night!

For those interested, I stored my nodes neighbors in the node class itself so when I came to checking neighbors I didn't need to use the double for loop, I could just loop around a given nodes neighbors array.

Thanks again mate!